# Angular2/Ionic 5: How to avoid displaying toolbar with router-outlet in some of its child components?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ionic5, router-outlet

```
<app-toolbar *ngIf="!showToolbar">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-menu-button color="light"></ion-menu-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <app-toggle-calendar-list slot="end"></app-toggle-calendar-list>
</app-toolbar>

<ion-content>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

I am trying to add a toggle button on my mobile application that will change how data is displayed (list versus calendar). I created a separate component `toggle-calendar-list` in a `shared` module and I am using it as such (see code above). The problem is that this toolbar keeps on being displayed (as it should, given that I use router-outlet) in all its child pages(or components, using Angular terminology). What I want is to display this toolbar ONLY for some of its children. How can I achieve this behaviour in a "clean" manner? Thank you!
Mention: `app-toolbar` is another component in which I'm projecting the `ion-buttons` using `<ng-content>`